# Testflight Build Crashes - Could not load the aot data for mscorlib

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've been making Testflight builds for my application but it always crashes after launch. Debug and AdHoc builds are okay.

This is the log I get from the device:

> : Xamarin.iOS: Could not load the aot data for mscorlib from
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/17079537-7534-4E19-A690-CE972568506D/appname.app/.monotouch-64/mscorlib.arm64.aotdata:
>   No such file or directory
>
> : * Assertion at ../../../../../mono/mono/mini/aot-runtime.c:1692,
>   condition `data' not met

Is there anything I need to do in the release build specifically to avoid this crash?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is facing this issue, I resolved this by adding these scripts in the Custom Commands:

```
Before Build
rm -rf bin
Working Directory: ${ProjectDir}
```

and

```
Before Build
rm -rf obj
Working Directory: ${ProjectDir}
```

By doing this, the builds are compiled properly by Xamarin.